# how to find inner product and linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

1.)  $p=p(x)$ and $q=q(x)$ are polinom in $P_2$. Defined by $<p,q>=p(0)q(a)+p(\frac{1}{2})$$q(b)+p(1)q(c)$ for certain $a,b,c$ such that the $<.,.>$  is inner product in$P_2$ . Find the value of $\left\lVert 4x^2-1\right\rVert$

I can not determine the value of a,b,c such that <,> is inner product

2.) $T_1 : R^(3x3)$ -> R and $T_2 : R^(3x3)->R^(3x3)$ are linear transformation defined by $T_2(A)=A^T$. If $A=$\begin{matrix} a & b & c \\d & e & f \\g & h & i \\ \end{matrix} and $(T_1(T_2(A))=T_1(A)$  , find $T_1(A)$

$T_1(A)=T_1(A^T)$ using this fact how can we do for solving this question

Comment: @DonAntonio can you give the absolute value for ∥4x^2-1∥ ? or just in variable a,b,c?

Comment: This site is not for dumping undigested homework questions. Tell us what you know about these questions, please! Also, what is "Jika"?

Comment: @lio Reading what you wrote, only as function of $\;a,b,c\;$ ...and that is not "absolute value", though I guess one could think of if that way. Its name is **norm** .

Comment: @DonAntonio i think find ∥ 4x^2-1∥ for exact real number, which not using a,b,c as variable in the value of ∥ 4x^2-1∥

Comment: Then you have to do much, but really much more work than what you asked. You must first find $\;a,b,c\;$ such that the given function is *really* an inner product...and then calculate that element's norm.

Comment: OK, lio, you want to determine $a,b,c$ such that $\langle,\rangle$ is an inner product. The first thing to do is to write down the definition of an inner product. Can you do that?

Comment: Are you still there, lio?

Comment: Earth to lio, come in, please.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left\|4x^2-1\right\|^2=\langle 4x^2-1,\,4x^2-1\rangle=4\langle x^2,\,x^2\rangle-8\langle x^2,\,1\rangle+\langle 1,\,1\rangle$$

and now apply the definition. For example, taking $\;q(x):=x^2\;$ , we get

$$\langle x^2,\,x^2\rangle=q(0)q(a)+q\left(\frac12\right)q(b)+q(1)q(c)=\frac{b^2}4+c^2$$

and etc.

Comment: I think part of the point is that $a,b,c$ have to be chosen carefully to make the thing an inner product.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I would also think that would be a nice exercise, yet that is *not* what is asked in the question...Perhaps they just want the value of $\;\left\|4x^2-1\right\|\;$ as a function of $\;a,b,c\;$ .

Comment: @GerryMyerson I already edit the question.I misinterpreted the question maybe. can you help me to answer this question?